# Django - Retrieve Unauthenticated User object

Tags: django

As the titles states, I have a need for users to retrieve User information of different users, whether or not they're authenticated.

I have a 'profile' template with some logic to either display static user information (for public) or editable user information (for the user it belongs to).

**PROBLEM:** The condition in my template is returning "true" - the User object appears to be authenticated BUT it's not.  If I navigate from that page (profile) no user logged in.

I'm fairly new to Django.  Am I not retrieving the User object correctly in my view.py?

**views.py**

```
def GetProfileById(request, userid):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=userid)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    try:
        user_profile = user.get_profile()
    except Exception:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    context = {'user': user, 'user_profile': user_profile}
    return render_to_response('profile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**profile.html**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <form id="form-about" class="form-horizontal" action="{% url update-user-profile %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ about_form.first_name }}</p>
        <p>{{ about_form.last_name }}</p>
        <p>{{ about_form.birthday }}</p>
        <p>{{ about_form.profession }}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

{% else %}

     <p><b>Name:</b> {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
     <p><b>DOB:</b> {{ user_profile.birthday }}</p>
     <p><b>Profession:</b> {{ user_profile.profession }}</p>
     <p><b>Member since:</b> {{ user.date_joined|date:'Y-M-d'  }}</p>
     <p><b>Last login:</b> {{ user.last_login|date:'Y-M-d @ H:i' }}</p>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you expecting `.is_authenticated()` to tell you if the User record, coming from the database, is currently logged in?

Comment: If you are clicking a link and then the user is not logged in, doesn't mean they were not logged in previously.

Comment: I want the page to have two behaviors.  1) If the profile being requested belongs to the user that is currently logged in for a particular session, the page should have form(s) so the user can update his/her information.  2) For all other requests (authenticated or not), display the profile information in static form (i.e. not editable....no forms).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like, what you're trying to do is, if a user is currently logged in, you want to show a form that lets them update a profile.

So the problem is:

1. In your view, you're setting `user` to a User object from the database.
2. This object does not represent or contain information about whether the current user is logged in. It's just the record from the database.
3. You want to check `request.user`, which represents the User object for the user who requested the web page.

So in your template, change:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

to:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  I will make this change later this evening and report back to you.  Thanks!

If this is the case, then why is user.is_authenticated return true??

Comment: Well according to the docs, an instantiated User's is_authenticated() method always returns true.  How dumb is that?  So as a workaround, once I get a User object in my views function, I create a dictionary with the User data I need for my template(s).

Comment: You may need to add the request context processor to your settings.py file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're confusing `user` and `request.user`. The former is the user being displayed, the latter is the user that is currently logged in, or an AnonymousUser if no one is logged in.

You want to display that form if the user that is currently logged in and the user being displayed are the same, right? Then just change

```python
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

To

```python
{% ifequal user request.user %}
```